# Zod Validation fails: 'Expected array received object' error while uploading multiple images

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, rtk-query, zod

zod schema

```
const createTourSchema = object({ 
images:array(string())
})
```

onChange event

```
const [tourImages, setTourImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
const handleImagesChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      const fileList = Object.values(files);
      setTourImages(fileList);
    }
  }
```

```
  const onSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<ICreateTourInput> = async (
    values: any
  ) => {
      const uploadedImageUrls = [];
      for (const image of tourImages) {
        const imageFormData = new FormData();
        imageFormData.append('file', image);
        imageFormData.append(
          'upload_preset',
          import.meta.env.VITE_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET
        );
        const imageUploadRes = await uploadImage(imageFormData);
        const imageUrl = (imageUploadRes as any)?.data?.secure_url;
        if (imageUrl) {
          uploadedImageUrls.push(imageUrl);
        }
      }
      console.log(uploadedImageUrls);

      await createTour({
        ...values,
        imageCover: imageCoverUrl,
        images: uploadedImageUrls,
      });
}
```

createTour and uploadImage are rtk mutations.

```
<FormInput
 name="images"
 labelText="Tour Images"
 type="file"
 multiple={true}
 onChange={handleImagesChange}
/>
```

I am also react-hook-form.

I want to get hold of the images from input and then upload them to cloudinary. Get the urls of uploaded images in an array and send it to the server with other data required for creating a tour.

Comment: Where are you using `createTourSchema`?

Comment: I infer the type from it and pass it to useForm hook as well as the submit handler ` const methods = useForm<ICreateTourInput>({
    resolver: zodResolver(createTourSchema),
  });`

Comment: Can we see where you are using Zod to parse the values? Also, have you console logged the data that is being parsed? - because it might actually not be an array.